# UILabel Address label is blank and Local Declaration hides instance variable

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Xcode, and I am attempting to have my app access the Address Book, choose a person, and then create NSString values for the person (First Name, Last Name, Organization, Address, Email and Telephone Number) I can pull the first and last name, the organization, the first email entered (it would be nice to display all of the email address, and let the user choose), and the first phone number entered in (again, it would be nice to be able to choose), but the address for the person is always blank. I would really appreciate any help you can provide. In addition, I keep getting local declaration hides instance variable warnings - I have no idea how to resolve these.

```
#import "TACustomer.h"

@interface TACustomer ()

@end

@implementation TACustomer

@synthesize custfirstName;
@synthesize custlastName;
@synthesize custOrganization;
@synthesize custEmail;
@synthesize custAddress;
@synthesize custphoneNumber;



- (IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender
{
    // Creating the Address Book Picker
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    // Place the delegate of the picker to the control.
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    // Showing the picker.
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

}



- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
    //assigning control back to the main controller.
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}



- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{

    [self displayPerson:person];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    return NO;

}



- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                            property:(ABPropertyID)property
                          identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{


    // Only inspect the value if it's an address.
    if (property == kABPersonAddressProperty)
    {

        //Set up an ABMultiValue to hold the address values; copy from a book record.
        ABMutableMultiValueRef multicustValue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);


        // Set up an NSArray and copy values into it.
        NSArray *thecustArray = (__bridge id)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(multicustValue);


        // Figure out which values we want and store the index.
        const NSUInteger customerIndex = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier (multicustValue, identifier);

        // Set up an NSDictionary to hold the contents of the array.
        NSDictionary *custDict = [thecustArray objectAtIndex:customerIndex];

        // Set up NSStrings to hold the keys and values. First, how many are there?
        const NSUInteger theCount = [custDict count];
        NSString * __unsafe_unretained keys[theCount];
        NSString *__unsafe_unretained values[theCount];

        // Get the keys and values from the CFDictionary.
        [custDict getObjects:values andKeys:keys];



        // Set the address label's text.
        NSString *customeraddress;
        customeraddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@, %@, %@",
                   [custDict objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey],
                   [custDict objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey],
                   [custDict objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey],
                   [custDict objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey],
                   [custDict objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryKey]];

        self.custAddress.text = customeraddress;


    }
        return NO;
}



- (void)displayPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{

    // Get Customer First Name
    NSString* custfirstname = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

    self.custfirstName.text = custfirstname;


    // Get Customer Last Name
    NSString* custlastname = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonLastNameProperty);

    self.custlastName.text = custlastname;


    // Get Customer Organization
    NSString* custorganization = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonOrganizationProperty);

    self.custOrganization.text = custorganization;



    //Get Customer Email Address
    NSString* custemail = nil;
    ABMultiValueRef custemailAddresses = ABRecordCopyValue (person,kABPersonEmailProperty);

    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(custemailAddresses) > 0)
    {
        custemail = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(custemailAddresses, 0);

    } else
    {
        custemail = @"[None]";

    }
    self.custEmail.text = custemail;
    CFRelease(custemailAddresses);


    // Get Customer Phone Number
    NSString* custphone = nil;
    ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue (person,kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0)
    {
        custphone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);

    } else
    {
        custphone = @"[None]";

    }
    self.custphoneNumber.text = custphone;
    CFRelease(phoneNumbers);


bundle:nil;

//[self.navigationController pushViewController:tempExamInfoView animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: Please tell us where the error occurs, just post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Can you try priting `customeraddress` before setting to `self.custAddress.text`. What is its value printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no answer for the problem that the address data is blank.

To get rid of the "local declaration hides instance variable" warning you need to use different variable names that do not clash with the names of the properties you are synthesizing.

For instance, in `displayPerson:` you have a local variable `custfirstname`. Because this uses the same name as a property, the local variable hides the instance variable of the same name that is being synthesized.

If you want to keep the local variable name, I believe it is also possible to tell `@synthesize` to use a different name for the instance variable that it generates. I am not familiar with the syntax, so if you want to go that way you have to look it up yourself.